# Getting Docker logs in filebeat

Tags: docker, kibana, filebeat

I am trying to get docker logs from filebeat

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/*/frameworks/*/executors/*/*/*/std*
    - /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/*/frameworks/*/executors/*/*/*/*.log
  json.message_key: log
  json.keys_under_root: true
  processors:
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
```

But I am getting only the docker.container.id = "slaves"

As per this [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/enrich-docker-logs-with-filebeat) if I provide path = /var/lib/docker/containers//.log , I should get the proper container id. But my docker logs are not into this location.
Anyone please suggest how to get all container fields from any logs path in filebeat.

Comment: if you use docker-compose, you can makes filebeat with elk-stack on docker in easy way. refer to this repository : [elk-with-filebeat-by-docker-compose](https://github.com/gnokoheat/elk-with-filebeat-by-docker-compose)